# Automatic img zooming?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a bunch of images being displayed one at a time in a div. The images are all a few thousand pixels by a few thousand pixels.

For example, one image is 4353x2721.

When I preview the page, it zooms in the picture and cuts out things along only the top and bottom edges. It remains the right width.

I need it to just resize it so that it fits the screen/div properly without cutting any parts.

The CSS for that section is:

```
.largeImage img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

If I add `height:100%;`, it still doesn't work. Still zooms in.

Comment: refer this link https://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/a4cRb/ or http://jsfiddle.net/onury/3k332/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `max-width: 100%` and `max-height: 100%` for image. It will make image to fit its larged dimension to parent container limits and scale down other dimension.

Look at snippet:

```css
.largeImage {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.largeImage img {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="largeImage">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-640-480-5.jpg">
</div>

<div class="largeImage">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-h-c-640-1233-7.jpg">
</div>
```